# How to return mutiple value using ajax in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

JQUERY

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        type: 'POST',   
        success:function () 


        var id = html.$id;
        var name = html.$name;  
        alert(id);
        alert(name); 
    });
```

SAVE.PHP

```
<?php
    include("db.php");

    $sql = "INSERT into test(Name)values('') ";

    if (mysql_query($sql))
    {
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        echo $name = "Peter";
        echo $id;
    }
?>
```

How can retrieve specific data and store in a specific variable in my Jquery?
Please ignore my Name in php, because I just randomly assign variable to it

How to return two different data, and store them in 2 variable?

I know it is incorrect, please tell me the correct way of doing it

Comment: read up about jquery ajax calls. Also, read up about parsing objects. You also need to return an object from your php code.

Answer (score 1):

JS

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'save.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON'
}).done(function(data) {
    alert(data.id);
    alert(data.name); 
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    include("db.php");

    $sql = "INSERT into test(Name)values('') ";

    if (mysql_query($sql)) {
        $arr = array(
                     "id"   => mysql_insert_id(),
                     "name" => "Peter"
                    );

        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I could get the return value of the data.id

Comment: $.ajax({
    url: 'save.php',
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'JSON',  
    success:function (data)
     {
      alert(data.id);
       
     
    }
   });

Answer (score 0):

You can return the value as in `JSON` format in key-value pair. Since I do not have much knowledge over php, but if possible try to return any `JSON` or `XML` response from your php code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'save.php',
      type: 'POST',
      success:function(response) 
        // here you can use response to display your value
      });
```